# gmaps4rails and HTML5 geolocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, geocoding, gmaps4rails

I believe I am using gmaps4rails v2. The code is producing a blank page and the source is showing

```
<div class="container">

  <div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
<style>
    .gm-style img { max-width: none; }
    .gm-style label { width: auto; display: inline; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else{x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {
        handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
            markers = handler.addMarkers([
                {
                    "lat": position.coords.latitude,
                    "lng": position.coords.longitude,
                    "picture": {
                        "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                        "width":  36,
                        "height": 36
                    },
                    "infowindow": "You!"
                }
            ]);
            handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();
        });
    }
</script>
```

I believe this means it is not obtaining the coordinates correctly. I would use Geocoder, but it doesn't work with everything that HTML5's geolocation does. Geocoder only works by IP and I need it to work for GPS and other ways as well. IP is not always correct.

My code is as follows...

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
<style>
    .gm-style img { max-width: none; }
    .gm-style label { width: auto; display: inline; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else{x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {
        handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
            markers = handler.addMarkers([
                {
                    "lat": position.coords.latitude,
                    "lng": position.coords.longitude,
                    "picture": {
                        "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                        "width":  36,
                        "height": 36
                    },
                    "infowindow": "You are here!"
                }
            ]);
            handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: when do you execute `getLocation`?

Comment: yes I apologize. I have found my dumb mistake. I can't believe I didn't run the script.

Comment: just added an example of geolocation on http://apneadiving.github.io